# Could the word "continuum" be applied to theposition of the hands of an analog clock?

Tags: mathematical-modeling

The word "continuum", in term of measurement, is defined as:

> models explain variation as involving gradual quantitative transitions
>   without abrupt changes or discontinuities. In contrast, categorical
>   theories or models explain variation using qualitatively different
>   states.[1]

So let's assume that we want to make a model ( based on time ) of the position of one of the hands of all "tick-tocking" watches, for which every hand has 60 discrete positions.

If we assume that we made that model could we apply the word "continuum" to it ? Would the lack of a continuity ( in terms of position ) contradict with the definition of the word "continuum" ?

Comment: No, by any reasonable definition of continuum, no finite set is one.